# Lazarus cannot find Uses Generics

Tags: delphi, generics, lazarus, tobjectlist

Why can't I uses `Generics.Collections` or `Generics.Default` or even just `Generics` in Lazarus?

```
Uses
  Generics.Collections;
```

```
Uses
  System.Generics.Default;
```

```
Uses
  System.Generics.Collections;
```

```
Uses
  System.Generics.Default,
  System.Generics.Collections;
```

```
Uses
  SysUtils,
  Generics;
```

> Cannot find Generics.Collections used by uTest of the Project Inspector.
>   Cannot find Generics.Defaults used by uTest of the Project Inspector.
>   Cannot find Generics used by uTest of the Project Inspector.

Comment: Your question title does not make sense. You can't be using *Delphi Lazarus*, because there is no such thing. The code you've posted (with zero effort to even attempt to format it correctly) is not Lazarus/FreePascal code; it's Delphi code. Lazarus does not have the `System.Generics` namespace, AFAIK. You could try reading the Lazarus/FP documentation about generics to find out where to find the appropriate units. Delphi and FreePascal are not the same product, and they're not identical. They have similarities, but it's not a case of *everything is directly compatible, so just compile it*.

Comment: I don't want put the entire code here when just the USES won't compile. I just put all thinks i tryed on the uses declaration.But you said something i didn't know. I was assuming Lazarus would be the the "free delphi" thing. Like you have Visual studio Ultimate or just Express. At work we use the Embarcadouro IDE XE2 for delphi, and i use those USES there. I was following some videos about delphi 7 where the guys said that you can download lazarus if you don't have acess to delphi IDE

Comment: Or a similar IDE like Eclipse and NetBeans, i didn't know that was different program language.

Comment: No. Lazarus is an open-source project that started out to reproduce the original Delphi 7 IDE, VCL, and RTL while being cross-platform; FreePascal is the open-sourced compiler that is being used for Lazarus. Delphi and Lazarus are in no way related. Delphi is (and always has been) a commercial product. There was a single free, very limited edition produced once, but it's long since disappeared (way before generics). And Delphi 7 had no concept of generics whatsoever. Eclipse and NetBeans are Java IDEs, so I don't know how they're in any way relevant.

Comment: I was just making a example of what i thought about Embarcadouro XE2 IDE and Lazarus. Assuming they were same language they should compile, but as you already said, it's wrong. I didn't "format" because i'm already spend more then one hour trying to add a import for a unit. I could do this with close eye in .Net, well this isn't .Net, so, lesson learned.

Comment: @KenWhite: technically, Eclipse is a more general-purpose IDE that supports several toolchains, including but not limited to Java.

Comment: @Remy: Point taken, but they're still not related to the question at hand.

Comment: *I didn't format because I'm alread spend more than one hour* - what does that have to do with formatting code here? It's a minor effort: Copy/paste your code, and either hit Ctrl+K on the keyboard or click the `{}` toolbar button (or for a single line, indent it four spaces). The time you spent searching has absolutely nothing to do with how you format code in your post here. You're using this site, so you should spend the time to properly use it.

Comment: try using :http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=20965.0 if You really need it

Comment: Easy guys, he's a beginner in Pascal. Let's help him not beat him.

Comment: I deleted Delphi from the question title and now everything makes sense. It is a 100% valid question now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Lazarus](http://www.lazarus-ide.org) is the IDE for the open-source [FreePascal](http://www.freepascal.org) compiler.  Neither of them have *ANYTHING* to do with Delphi.  FreePascal is a completely separate Pascal compiler than the one Delphi uses.

FreePascal has a Delphi compatibility mode, and does implement various Delphi units and classes, to help users port existing Delphi code to FreePascal.

But as far as Generics is concerned, FreePascal provides its own Generics syntax and implementation that is different from, and not compatible with, Delphi's Generics (actually, support for Delphi-style Generics was added in [FreePascal 2.6](http://wiki.freepascal.org/FPC_New_Features_2.6.0), but "*still may be not 100% compatible*" with Delphi.  Also see [delphi language features which fpc does not have - Generics Syntax](http://wiki.freepascal.org/delphi_language_features_which_fpc_does_not_have#Generics_Syntax)).

Read FreePascal's documentation for more details about its flavor of Generics:

http://wiki.freepascal.org/Generics

http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refch8.html

The `System.Generics.Default` and `System.Generics.Collections` units are only available in Delphi, they do not exist in FreePascal.  However, there is a [3rd party implementation](https://github.com/dathox/generics.collections) of these units available for FreePascal.

Answer (score 4):

Generics.Collections library (with Generics.Defaults module) has been added to FPC trunk as rtl-generics package in r34229. Latest version of precompiled FPC trunk (with Generics.Collections) for Win32 + Lazarus trunk available at http://newpascal.org . The repository of Generics.Collections ( https://github.com/dathox/generics.collections ) will be still used for maintenance (should be synced often with FPC trunk).﻿

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use the [Generics.Collections](https://github.com/maciej-izak/generics.collections) package made by Maciej Izak.

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1:** Try installing Sparta/generics from Lazurus packages installer form (I don't know if it is possible).

**OPCION 2:** intalling [this](https://github.com/maciej-izak/generics.collections) manualy.

I did it by doing this (may be not the best way):

1. Download the .zip from [here](https://github.com/maciej-izak/generics.collections)
2. I unzipped in c:/temporal
3. And from the command line in that path do: "fpc fpmake.pp" + ENTER, which should generate "fpmake.exe".
4. Double click on fpmake.exe

It seems like this is installing the component on lazarus/components/sparta/generics, the problem is that you cannot access it from Lazarus Packages Installer form.

**OPTION 3:**
If it is not possible, you can try this way if it is just for one project (not the good way but it worked for me):

1. Download the .zip from [here](https://github.com/maciej-izak/generics.collections/tree/master)
2. Copy the "src" folder at some place and rename it (i.e.: src_generic)
3. Add that path in "project/options" => "Paths" (sorry mine is in Spanish).
   [image]